# Waiting for window to be ready before calling AutomationElement.FromHandle

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

I have a windows hook which listens to new windows being created and forward to .NET module which performs some automation.

The problem is when few applications are launched, when `AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd)` is called, the application is crashing with `System.InvalidOperationException`

```
Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
```

The only operation I am doing when the crash occurred is trying to get the `AutomationElement` from the handle `hwnd` using `AutomationElement.FromHandle`.
The exception itself states that it occurs

> The exception is done on purpose to prevent reentrancy bugs caused by
>   weirdness resulting from altering the visual tree, while such an event
>   (which itself has been triggered by the visual tree altering) is
>   firing.

I'm looking for a way where I can call this function when the window is ready and not causing these exceptions in the target application.

```
try{
        AutomationElement temp = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd);
        LogMessage("Found Element from HWND " + hwnd.ToString("x") + "(" + hwnd + ")");
        return Pool.Add(temp, msg);
}
catch (System.Exception ex){
       LogMessage("Exception while element from HWND " + hwnd.ToString("x") + "(" + hwnd + ")");
}
```

Is there a way where I can detect if the target window is ready and then call my function? The only way I found so far in making this work is using

`Thread.Sleep(3000);`

But, it's not always guaranteed that it will work and wait may be too long in some cases.

I know that listening to `UIAutomation Events` may solve this problem as the events give the `AutomationElement` itself in callback. But, unfortunately, I have to rely on events from hook itself.

Answer (score 0):

as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987380)

you can use

```
while (p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero);
```

to wait until the window is ready